Imo shortlisted question about sets and summation
Let $n\ge2$ be a positve integer and $a_1, a_2, ...., a_n $ be real numbers such that $$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + .... + a_n = 0.$$
Define the set $A$ by $$A = \{(i,j) |1\le i< j\le n,|a_i-a_j|\geq 1\}$$
Prove that, if $A$ is not empty, then $$\sum_{(i,j) \in A} a_ia_j <  0$$
What I have tried:
I defined sets B and C by $$B = \{(i,j) | 1 \le i,j \le n, |a_i - a_j| \geq 1 \}$$ $$C = \{(i,j) | 1 \le i,j \le n, |a_i - a_j| < 1\}$$
I can't seem to penetrate further and can only get up to here.

Here is the problem picture in case my latex isn't appealing


+1 to your posting for one reason: you made the extra effort of both presenting the problem in mathjax (i.e. latex) and presenting an image of the problem.  Often, question posters will misinterpret the assigned question when they present it, or omit pertinent information.  By taking the approach that you did, you killed two birds with one stone:  presented the problem in mathjax, as required, and provided solid evidence that you were not misinterpreting the problem or omitting pertinent info.

key info omitted. In defining set A, $i < j$ and not $i \le j$

I have not solved this problem yet, but I would recommend "penetrating further" via $ \sum a_i a_j = - \sum a_i^2/2 <0 $ to use the condition, and seeing how that splits up over sets $B, C$. My guess is that the sum over $C$ is positive (given B non-empty), hence sum over $B$ is negative.

The official shortlist contains solutions. Why not look at those?

I know that there are solutions but i want to know the motivation behind them, which is explained when someone here explains there solution.

@MethukaWeerawala which part of the official solution do you not understand?

the part after my statement @sku

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2279021p17829013

I need to know the intentions behind it by someone who solved it

@MethukaWeerawala The motivation is as I described in my comment. How can we show that the sum over C is positive? It almost certainly has to be, since the terms differ only by a small amount (so are almost like squares), and the only trouble is when you get to the QR terms per sku's solution. So we split them out and look at them. The solution is basically "Given that the result is true, let's check all of the details". $\quad$ Note, not everyone explains the motivation behind the solution. Some just post the solution.

$\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2 = 0 \implies \sum\limits_{i =1}^n a_i^2 +  2\sum\limits_{1 \le i,j \le n} a_ia_j = 0$
Therefore we have $\sum\limits_{1 \le i,j \le n} a_ia_j = \sum\limits_{i,j \in B} a_ia_j + \sum\limits_{i,j \in C} a_ia_j < 0$
Therefore it suffices to prove $\sum\limits_{i,j \in C} a_ia_j > 0$
Now define four sets of indices $P,Q,R,S$ as follows:
$P = \{i | a_i \le -1\}$
$Q = \{i | -1 < a_i \le 0\}$
$R = \{i | 0 < a_i < 1\}$
$S = \{i | a_i \ge 1\}$
Now $i$ and $j$ can belong to each of these sets.
Let $PP$ define the indices where $i \in P$ and $j \in P$
The full set of possibilities include:
$PP: $ $\sum a_ia_j > 0$ (some of these terms can be outside $C$)
$PQ:$ $\sum a_ia_j>0$ (some of these terms can be outside $C$)
$PR:$ will not be in $C$
$PS:$ will not be in $C$
$QQ:$ $\sum a_ia_j > 0$
$QR:$ $\sum a_ia_j > 0$ or $\sum a_ia_j < 0$
$QS:$ will not be in $C$
$RR:$ $\sum a_ia_j > 0$
$RS:$ $\sum a_ia_j > 0$
$SS:$ $\sum a_ia_j > 0$ (some of these terms can be outside $C$)
The positive sums are from $PP, PQ, QQ, RR, SS$. We only consider positive terms from $PP$ and $SS$ where $i = j$. This will give us the inequality.
So we have $\sum\limits_{i,j \in C} a_ia_j \ge \sum\limits_{i \in P \cup S} a_i^2 + \sum\limits_{i,j \in Q \cup R} a_ia_j = \sum\limits_{i \in P \cup S} a_i^2 + \left(\sum\limits_{i \in Q \cup R} a_i\right)^2 \ge 0$
The first inequality becomes an equality when both sides have same negative terms and this implies $|a_i - a_j| < 1$ whenever $i,j \in Q\cup R$. This will effectively eliminate many of the positive sums which we ignored.
The second inequality becomes equality only when $\sum\limits_{i \in P \cup S} a_i^2 = 0$. This implies $P\cup S = \emptyset$. And given that $|a_i - a_j| < 1$, this eliminates $Q \cup R$ and thus $A = \emptyset$ which is not true and hence we get the strict inequality.
ps: The solution is from the IMO shortlist. I merely tried to explain it.
